# How to dynamically include all template partials when using a module in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include, meanjs

I have several modules that require some template partials to be loaded whenever the module is used.  I am storing these files in a folder called partials inside each module subfolder.  My starting point for my app is **meanjs**, and I am storing partials file are in public/modules//partials/*.html.

I have seen several ng-include and directive examples, but being new to AngularJS each sample I read confuses me further as to what is best practice / most AngularJS appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your partials whenever you wants.
To load them all use angular [template cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache).

Use Grunt or gulp to generate automatically. Personally I use gulp.

Here is my working example of one of my project.

install nodejs and npm

`npm intall gulp -g`

`npm install gulp-angular-templatecache`

create `gulpfile.js`

```
var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('generate', function () {
    gulp.src('public/*/partials/*.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('templates.js', {module: 'YOURMODULENAME', standalone: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});
 gulp.task('watch-partials', function () {
    gulp.watch('public/*/partials/*.html', ['generate']);
});
```

then use it like this:

`gulp generate` - to regenerate partials

`gulp watch-partials` - watch file changes, if partials are changed it automatically run `generate` task for you. :)

One more thing, dont forget to include template.js in your html file

`<script src="public/js/template.js"></script>`

Every time you change your partial dont forget to regenerate your template cache.

Comment: GruntJS modules for this objective: https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js
or https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates

Comment: @qwent Thanks! Thats what I love about Stackoverflow, answers to the questions I should have asked :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of `$templateCache`. In your partials folder define the templates like this:

```
angular.module('yourTemplateModule', []).run('$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
   $templateCache.put('yourTemplate', '<div>...some HTML here...</div>');
}
```

Then create a module, named for example 'app.tpls', which has as dependencies all your template modules. Inject it as dependency to your main app module, probably located in *meanjs* and now you have your templates ready whenever you need them in your application. You retrieve them by calling:

```
$templateCache.get('yourTemplate');
```